# Retrieving None as an entry_set django

Tags: django, django-views

**profile**

```
class SeekerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    current_salary = models.IntegerField()
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='applicants')
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='applicants/documents')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

**Skillset model**

```
class Seekerskillset(models.Model):
    skill_set = models.ForeignKey(Skillset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seeker = models.ForeignKey(SeekerProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill_level = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Seeker skill set'
```

**But when i am trying to get the entry set i am receiving None**

> even though i am clearly having entries for amir

```
>> from seekerbuilder.models import SeekerProfile
>>> obj = SeekerProfile.objects.get(id=1)
>>> print(obj)
amir
>>> print(obj.seekerskillset_set)
seekerbuilder.Seekerskillset.None
>>> for val in obj.seekerskillset_set:
...     print(val)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: Should be `seekerskillset_set.all()`, so `for val in obj.seekerskillset_set.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten `.all()`:

```
>>> for val in obj.seekerskillset_set.all():
...     print(val)
```